# Using identity in sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server, orm

I have a table of Owner:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Owner] (
    [OwnerID]     INT        IDENTITY (1, 1)    NOT NULL,
    [Name]        NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Username]    NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Password]    NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Phone]       NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Mail]        NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Description] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Image]       IMAGE         NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([OwnerID] ASC)
);
```

And I want the key field "OwnerID" to auto increment (starting from 1), but it doesn't work.

The c# code is:

```
Owner owner = new Owner();
owner.Username = ((TextBox)CreateUserWizardStep1.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("UserName")).Text;
owner.Name = ((TextBox)CreateUserWizardStep1.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("Name")).Text;
owner.Password = ((TextBox)CreateUserWizardStep1.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("Password")).Text;
owner.Phone = ((TextBox)CreateUserWizardStep1.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("Phone")).Text;
owner.Mail = ((TextBox)CreateUserWizardStep1.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("Email")).Text;
owner.Description = ((TextBox)CreateUserWizardStep1.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("Description")).Text;
```

When I debug I can see that the field OwnerID is set to 0 (I don't know why) and at the end I have an error message:

> The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the  configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs.

Comment: Just a side note, you want to remove `Password` column from your db table and replace it with two columns `PasswordHash` and `PasswordSalt`. Never store passwords. Encrypted or not. Always store password hash with password-specific salt.

Comment: This is *not* the actual server-side error, this is the error returned to a WCF client when the service fails. It's impossible to help unless you provide relevant info, ie the *actual* exception, the ORM you use and the *code* you used to store the entities

Comment: The fact that ID equals 0 while debugging is nothing strange since it is default value for non-nullable integer. EF lets database auto increment identity column for creating an entity.

Answer (score 1):

If your using EF then you should create a Configuration for `Owner`:

```
class OwnerConfiguration: EntityTypeConfiguration<Owner>
    {
        public OwnerConfiguration()
        {
            HasKey(x => x.OwnerId);
        }
    }
```